# in scripting bridge how can i send shortcut with 2 modifiers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scripting-bridge

I was trying to replicate "take a screenshot shortcut" (cmd+shift+3) via cocoa and scripting bridge

```
SystemEventsApplication * sysEvent = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.systemevents"];
[sysEvent keyCode:20 using:SystemEventsEMdsCommandDown];
```

but i can't send more than one SystemEventsEMds to the method.
In applescript is as easy as

```
key code 20 using {command down, shift down}
```

Comment: Why not use CGWindowList to take the screenshot yourself?

Comment: thanks, i'll expand on that for this specific case but i was curious on how to solve the general modifier problem

Answer (score -1):

I kinda solved this.
I was trying to get a cmd+shift+3 that serves, as all of you know, to take a screenshot.
shift+3 is in the italian keyboard = to "£"
so

```
[sysEvent keystroke:@"£" using:SystemEventsEMdsCommandDown];
```

does the trick
I'm still wondering how would i have done with a cmd+opt+something and how to manage localization...

Comment: That won't generalize to other keyboard layouts. In the US and Dvorak keyboard layouts, £ is *option*-3, so that would in fact be ⌘⌥3, rather than ⇧⌘3. This is why you should stick to keycodes (and only simulate hotkey presses at all when there isn't an alternative such as taking the screenshot yourself).